# Does Deligne's exceptional series lead to an "exceptional K-theory"?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology, exceptional-groups

To a certain extent, Deligne's exceptional series $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset G_2 \subset D_4 \subset F_4 \subset E_6 \subset E_7 \subset E_8$ plays a role analogous to the classical series $A_n \subset A_{n+1} \subset \dots \subset SL(\infty)$, $C_n \subset C_{n+1} \subset \dots \subset Sp(\infty)$, and $D_n \subset B_n \subset D_{n+1} \subset \dots \subset Spin(\infty)$.

One place the classical series occur is in constructions of K-theory. In particular, it is approximately true that if you apply the Quillen plus construction to $BSU(\infty)$, you get complex K-theory, and if you look instead at $\mathbb{F}$-points of $GL(\infty)$, you get algebraic K-theory of the field $\mathbb{F}$. I imagine that similar constructions starting with $Spin$ and $Sp$ give versions of real K-theory, but I don't know.

**Question:** What is the result of Quillen's plus construction applied to $BE_8$? Does it produce an "exceptional K-theory"?

Comment: What's the analog of $E(R)$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isn't $E_8$ connected, so that its classifying space is simply connected? (There's more than one thing you could mean by $E_8$, but aren't the real and complex forms are all connected?) Then what could it mean to apply the plus construction? Note, as in @AHusain's comment, that you need to specify a perfect normal subgroup of $\pi_1$ in order to speak about the plus construction. For the same reason, I'm confused when you talk about applying the plus construction to $BSU(\infty)$, which again is a simply connected space.

Comment: @DanRamras Right. I was imprecise in part because of a lack of knowledge (and in part because I haven't thought through things). I could mean to take the discrete group of points of E8 over some field. That group is usually simple...

Comment: You can construct "unstable" exceptional K-theory via Volodin's construction, using all unipotent radicals of Borel subgroups, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Volodin+model

$K_2$-part can be written in terms of generators and relations in Steinberg style. However, not much is known about stabilization etc. for Volodin's K-theory in general, apart from the classical case of $GL_n$.

Comment: What is the motivational idea behind that series? And shouldn't there be a $D_3$ in it?

Comment: @Sebastian You can read Deligne’s paper at https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/75_LaSerie.pdf (in French). D3=A3 is not there because it is in commensurate with G2.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the notation. From geometry, part of the series looks familiar, but instead of D4 maybe I would have expected B3 and B4. Then at least some of the quotients are spheres. Somehow I always believed that the sphere quotients were an essential feature of the classical series.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Perhaps. IIRC, Deligne's suggestion (which I think is known not to work) was that there might be a continuous family of symmetric monoidal categories, analogous to his $GL_t$, in which these eight entries were the "group" ones. (Incidentally, I think the groups he used were $G = Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ for the Lie algebras listed. So for example $D_4$ really means $PSO(8) \rtimes S_3$.) The point was that these eight groups have some modules that fuse in some particular way.

Comment: For me the interest was that, for the simply-connected groups with those names, these inclusions are all "level one", akin to the classical series $SL_n \subset SL_{n+1}$ and $Sp_n \subset Sp_{n+1}$ and, for $n\geq 5$, $Spin_n \subset Spin_{n+1}$. By "level one" I mean that the induced maps on $H^4(BG)$ are isomorphisms. So it is a sort of "homological stability", which is important in the K-theory case.